# How to check if the fragment exists

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to talk to the fragments from activity.

Here in my MainActivity I am adding multiple fragments ok so for fine.

My main requirement is I don't want to add if fragment is already added.

So how can we check this condition?

Please help me some one.

### code:-

```
 private void intializingFragments(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener intialization() {

        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int getId = v.getId();

                if (getId == R.id.first) {
                    intializingFragments(new Fragment1());

                } else if (getId == R.id.second) {
                    intializingFragments(new Fragment2());

                } else if (getId == R.id.third) {
                    intializingFragments(new Fragment3());
                } 
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Use this `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()` or you can also find by id, just make sure you assign tag to your fragment when you are adding it in the transaction.

Comment: check by using isAdded() method. if(yourFragment.isAdded(){//added}else{//not added}

Answer (score 34):

You can use findFragmentByTag() or findFragmentById() functions to get a fragment. If mentioned methods are returning null then that fragment does not exist.

```
Fragment fragmentA = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("frag1");
if (fragmentA == null) {
  // not exist
} else {
  // fragment exist
}
```

for example:- http://wiki.workassis.com/android-load-two-fragments-in-one-framelayout/

Answer (score 20):

You may find fragment in fragmentmanager:

```
List<Fragment> frags = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
for (Fragment f : frags) { 
  <find what you want>... 
}
```

Or you may add fragment with tag:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .add(R.id.frame, new MyFragment(), "frag1")
  .commit();
```

And find by tag

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag1");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment topFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
                if(topFragment!= null)
                {
                    transaction.remove(topFragment);
                    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragmentA, "FA");
                    transaction.commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragmentA, "FA");
                    transaction.commit();
                }
```

try this

```
private void intializingFragments(Fragment fragment) {
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment topFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        if(topFragment!= null)
        {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(topFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        else
        {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: FA what is meaning of it?

Comment: whenever you want to replace or remove the fragment so that requaried like this  FragmentA FA = (FragmentA) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FA");

Comment: Fragment topFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);

Comment: in this line what is "container" means?

Comment: Fragment topFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113484/discussion-between-krish-and-naveen-tamrakar).

Answer (score 4):

How to check whether a fragment exists, without knowing its resource ID or tag:

```kotlin
// MyActivity.kt
val exists: Boolean = supportFragmentManager
    .fragments
    .filterIsInstance<MyFragment>()
    .isNotEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways by which you can track the last added fragment. The simplest one is by finding the tag within fragment manager. Here is the sample code of it:

```
public boolean isFragmentPresent(String tag) {
    Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (frag instanceof HomeFragment) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use your own variable to check whether the last added fragment is the same as the current fragment. Here is the sample code for it:

```
public boolean isCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment && getLastAddedFragment() instanceof HomeFragment) { // getLastAddedFragment() is a method which return the last added fragment instance
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
if (isCurrentFragment(new HomeFragment())) {
    // Last added Fragment is the HomeFragment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for **popBackStack** Pop the last fragment transition from the manager's fragment back stack. If there is nothing to pop, false is returned. [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of previously added fragments from the fragment manager. Then just check whether the list contains your fragment object or not.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().contains(yourFragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one doesn't work

```
!getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().contains(fragment)
```

This works for me

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment::class.java.getSimpleName()) == null
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.