# Can I detect whether Fragment is already created or called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, retain

Can I detect whether the Fragment I am going to call is already called or created so that I can reuse it instead of recreating it?

Comment: You can manage the boolean variable in SharePrefrence onCreateView and onDestroy View.

Comment: you can find already created fragments using findFragmentByTag or findFragmentById. Please have a look on the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#findfragmentbyid

Comment: Yes, you can use `fragmentManager` and findout either of two ways: 1. `findFragmentByTag()` 2. `findFragmentById()`

Comment: I have tried ' findFragmentByTag()' but it is always showing 'null'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560712/how-to-check-if-the-fragment-exists

Answer (score 0):

The fragments have isVisible() method .

```
            if(fragment.isVisible()){
                //your code.//
            }
```

By this you can see if the fragment is already created or not.

Comment: will it work if i am checking this  in some other fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Test if `onCreateView` has been called

```
public abstract class SubFragment extends Fragment
{
    protected boolean onCreateViewCalled = false;

    public boolean hasOnCreateViewBeenCalled()
    {
        return onCreateViewCalled;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup Container, Bundle state){
        onCreateViewCalled = true;
        return null;
    }
}
```

for more details please read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView())

Answer (score 0):

You could use `findFragmentByTag()` :

> Finds a fragment that was identified **by the given tag either when
>   inflated from XML or as supplied when added in a transaction**.  This
>   first searches through fragments that are currently added to the
>   manager's activity; if no such fragment is found, then all fragments
>   currently on the back stack are searched.

So your code should look like this:

```
    val tag = "MyFragment"
    // add a tag to transaction
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame, fragment, tag)
        .commit()


    // check if fragment exists by the given tag
    var instance = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    if (fragment == null) {
        instance = MyFragment.newInstance()
    } else {
        // reuse fragment instance
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this in JAVA but it always shows null. below is my code:                                                         
    ft.add(id,fragment,tag).addToBackStack()
    ft.commit();'                                                                                                                    and checking fragment:                                                                                                                       'Fragment instance = getsupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag)'                     but instance is always null

Comment: @S.Ambika try : `addToBackStack(tag)`