# Why getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) always shows null value?

Tags: java, android, null, fragment, fragmentmanager

Why `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag)` always shows null value. I am calling Fragment using below code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager =getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_step, fragment,tag).hide(SourceFragment.this).addToBackStack((SourceFragment.class.getName()));
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Sorry it is `getFragmentManager()` not `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

If I have Fragment A and Fragment B. I call Fragment B from A using below code

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager =getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_step, fragment,TAG).hide(SourceFragment.this).addToBackStack((SourceFragment.class.getName()));
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now in Fragment B I have EditText & I have entered "Hello" in it, if I press back button from Fragment B then according to getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); it will resume Fragment A

Now if I again call Fragment B from Fragment A I want that FragmentB will not get created again and still I can see "Hello" inside EditText.

Note -- I do not want to use variables or shared pref for this as i have multiple fragments with multiple views like a big form. Is there anything that can just call fragment from its resume state instead of calling it again or if i can check if this fragment has already created . Thanks in advance
Also `ft.show(fragment)` is not working. Is there anything required to make it work?

Comment: `getFragmentManager()` and `getsupportFragmentManager()` return two different `FragmentManager`s. You cannot find `Fragment`s attached to one from the other.

Comment: Why use `getsupportFragmentManager()` when you're committing with `getFragmentManager()`?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `getFragmentManager()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856484/can-i-detect-whether-fragment-is-already-created-or-called#comment104009457_58857228 If so, then you'll need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. There are a few different things that could cause that.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes I am sure.That was a writing mistake. I am just using above code to call fragment and then trying to check whether fragment exits or not using `findFragmentByTag()` method and it is always showing null value

Comment: Well, if you're calling `findFragmentByTag()` right after the `commit()` call, it will return null then, because the `Fragment` will not have been attached yet. If that's not what's happening, then, as I mentioned above, we'll need to see a [mcve], since there are a few different possible causes.

Comment: I have seen these links before but nothing is working for this

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. The first link was to your comment on your last question where you show that you're using `getsupportFragmentManager()`. I was making sure that you do actually have the right code, currently. The second link is to a guide for creating an appropriate example for us. Neither of those was a link to a solution.

Comment: @MikeM. actually i am calling `findFragmentByTag()` in some other scenario. I have two fragments A and B . I am calling fragment B from A using above code now i want if i came back to A and again call B then it should not recreate. I want to use its already created instance using `findFragmentByTag`

Comment: TO use that instance i need to check it before calling so here i am using `findFragmentByTag`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MikeM. I have edited the question.

Comment: This is not how fragments and backstack work. Once you pop fragment out of backstack, it's gone. If you want to have it alive, use different container and don't use backstack.

Comment: Why you tag a `java` question with `kotlin`? I've re-tagged that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is rather vague, my best guess would be:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android will erase fragment and it's data when you remove fragment from backstack.

If you want to keep the state of fragment, just keep it in your stack.
How can you do that:

```
- Create a fake stack for app flow.
- Remove or add fragment in fake stack for flow, remove/add fragment from 
official stack if you don't want to keep it's state.
- Retrieve fragment by using it's tag.
```

This solution is not simple as using variable to save data in activity or using share preference. Another way, you can also create a model for each screen and just save data in to this model. Retrieve every time you want. It's your choice.

Ps: For more advantage, you can look for [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Hope this will help you!