# .commitNow() vs .commit(), which is more adequate?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, commit, fragmentmanager

I´m trying to clean up my code and I have a more basic question.

In my Activity, I'm just adding a Fragment ->

```
class OrderActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasAndroidInjector {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityOrderBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_order)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, OrderFragment())
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

I´m using commitNow() only if the Activity is "new" ( asking for the bundle state ), as I read in Android´s Documentation, commitNow make the commit syncronously  -- >

> *Commits this transaction synchronously. Any added fragments will be initialized and brought completely to the lifecycle state of their host and any removed fragments will be torn down accordingly before this call returns. Committing a transaction in this way allows fragments to be added as dedicated, encapsulated components that monitor the lifecycle state of their host while providing firmer ordering guarantees around when those fragments are fully initialized and ready. Fragments that manage views will have those views created and attached.*

Now, I just want to know if it is safe to replace commitNow for ".commit()".

I understand that commit can throw an exception if the Activity State was already saved, but, if I wrote it like this .. >

```
class OrderActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasAndroidInjector {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityOrderBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_order)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, OrderFragment())
                .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

This may not cause an error, but you are relying on an unrelated happen stance to manage your `Fragment`. When you could check if it already exists if not add it.

[How to check if the fragment exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560712/how-to-check-if-the-fragment-exists)

And whether `commit` is safe or not is up to how you are using the `Fragment`.

Is the `Fragment` strongly coupled with the containing `Activity` i.e. does `OrderActivity` talk directly to the `OrderFragment`?
If so then you could talk to the `Fragment` before it has been added which is generally a no-no if it has anything to do with a `view`.

If the `Fragment` is independent and manages itself then you should be fine.

They can still be used together but it needs to be 1 way `Fragment` -> `Activity` and  NOT  `Activity` -> `Fragment` as again `commit()` is async and the containing `Activity` could be talking to something that isn't "there".